# Rendering more than 1000 markers in react-leaflet takes ages and user experience is horrible, need to improve my approach

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have an array of 1000 min to 5000 max points to draw on my react-leaflet map. So my render function in the map component looks similar to:

```
renderMarkers = () => {
    return markers.map(
        (marker) => {
            return <Marker key={`${marker.id}`} position={[marker.lt, marker.lg]} ></Marker>
        }
    )
}

render() {
    <Map>
        {this.renderMarkers()}
    </Map>
}
```

My problem is that it takes normally 1 sec to 3 secs to render the html on the map and the user experience is horrible, since the window blocks a bit now and then when the map moves.

Is there anyway to divide all markers rendering in sections or let the window load that javascript async or show a loading icon while the map function runs?

Even if there is a better approach that the one that I am doing, would be great to know.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: does not have to do anything with clustering since it is already clustering the markers, has to do with showing somehow to the user that the javascript is running so he needs to wait, or render async so the map flows.

Comment: Clustering the markers should help to reduce the number of markers to be rendered.

Comment: Won't solve your problem outright, but your `key` should uniquely identify _the thing_ so a great way to wreck virtual dom diffing is to base it on some array position instead. Don't use `marker-${key}`, use some property from marker so that React doesn't waste time on rebuilding markers just because they swapped index in your array.

Comment: Ok, will try that tomorrow and let you know on the result. All markers are already clustered but the difference is not huge since the problem is the array map on 1000+ elements, not rendering the html resulting on the function

Comment: Added the id in a different way, still loads a bit slow.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the mistake of assuming that the reactive paradigm is better but forgetting that your function calls happen on every `render()` call.

As a rule of thumb, if the same operation returns the same value every time, and your code is running that operation a lot of times, then you should cache the result (or at the very least consider caching the result).

That is pretty much universal, but applies specifically to your case: your code is recalculating an array of `Marker` components (which becomes an expensive operation) on every `render()` call, instead of when the marker data changes. So cache its results, with something like:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

    getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if ( /* marker data has changed or */ !this._markerComponents) {
            this._markerComponents = markers.map( (marker, key) => 
                ( <Marker key={`marker-${key}`} position={[marker.lt, marker.lg]} ></Marker> )
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return ( <Map>{this._markerComponents}</Map> );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In order to use it I needed to upgrade to react 16.3.2 and declare the function as static. Your solution was already put into place if needed in shouldComponentUpdate, but this is not my problem, since when the user moves the map, the list is different. My problem has to do to show some loading div while javascript is running or render async the html of the markers. Edit: also declare the constructor

Comment: Nah, I think it's best to push the whole set of markers into Leaflet, let Leaflet handle their visibility. If you are doing something like dynamic loading from the network depending on the map state, I must ask that you specify that in your question.

Comment: @IvanSanchez ok, i considered caching it, but that didn't help. the page is still slow :>